# Primefaces dialog client validation not displaying

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, modal-dialog

I have a Primefaces 5.0 modal dialog on a composite control. The dialog has a few field marked as required. When the button on the dialog is clicked I expected the client validation to fire and it seems it does as the backing bean is not called, but the messages are not displaying:

```
<p:dialog id="dialogCorporateShareHolder" header="Shareholder (Company)" 
    widgetVar="dlgCorporateShareHolder" modal="true">
    <p:panelGrid columns="3" id="corporateShareHolderDetails">

        <h:outputLabel for="companyName" value="Company name"/>

        <p:inputText id="companyName" required="true" 
           value="#{cc.attrs.corporateShareHolder.companyName}" 
           label="Company name"/>

        <p:message for="companyName"/>

        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton id="submitCorporate" value="Submit" 
               update="corporateShareholders"
               actionListener="#{cc.attrs.controller.addCorporateShareHolder}"/>
        </f:facet>
    </p:panelGrid>

</p:dialog>
```

The dialog displays, the validation gets called (I'm pretty sure), but no message is displayed.

[image: Dialog box after the submit button is pressed]

Comment: Could you give it a try with update="corporateShareholders corporateShareholderDetails"

Comment: That worked! Add it as an answer @JaqenH'ghar

Comment: You was indeed just not updating the `<p:message>` at all. This kind of question *"I expected some component to be ajax-updated although I didn't specify it in `<p:commandButton update>`"* gets asked almost daily, we need to have a canonical dupe.

Comment: @SeanCoetzee Glad it worked, those things can be invisible... What is component with id=corporateShareholders, just some list?

Comment: Yeah, just a data grid.

Comment: what is `corporateShareholders` ? I dont see any id with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to update the `p:message` or a parent too, for example with

```
update="corporateShareholders corporateShareholderDetails"
```

Btw. I believe best practises are to

- have the dialog(s) last in xhtml, outside of other forms
- have a form inside the dialog itself

Comment: I would have liked to do that but my dialog is in a composite control which is within a form already.

Comment: No worry as it works for you already, I just wanted to remind myself :)

Comment: After your comments I started having other related issues and have ended up moving the dialogs out to their own form. MUCH better, so thanks.